# How to get user input in MySQL?

Tags: mysql, linux

Consider this simple Relation `MyRel(A, B)`
I wanted to display A based on value of B.
Here I would ask value of B from user. **Is it possible in MySQL? How can I do it?**

My query would be something like this `SELECT A FROM MyRel WHERE B = [user_input]`.

Also Note that I am **not** using PHP or any other language with MySQL. I will execute this on Linux terminal.

Comment: With no user interface your users needs to type in entire query into mysql console...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you are on the terminal anyway, why not write a little script around your functions and get the user input there, store it in variables and then send the mysql queries?

AFAIK there is no native method in MySQL that allows something like this, because SQL is there to query the **data**, not the user.

Small example:

```
echo "Please specify 'b'"
read b
mysql -u username -ppassword -D dbname -e "SELECT A, B FROM MyRel WHERE B = '$b'"
```

Answer (score 2):

You could use this command:

```
echo "SELECT A FROM MyRel WHERE B = [user_input]" | mysql -u login -ppassword db_name
```

Then you get the result on standard output. You can redirect it in a file or get it in a variable if you're in a bash script.